# Checking if element in array is already occupied

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making a two player tic tac toe game where the players enter a number in a 1-9 grid. Player X enters the desired position with variable Xp. And player O does the same. However I cannot make a if statement that checks if a player enters a spot of the grid that is already taken.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void showBoard(char board[], int turn, int Xp, int Op);
void winning(char board[]);


int main()
{

 int Xp=0, Op=0, turn=0;
 char board[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

showBoard(board, turn, Xp, Op);

return 0;
}

void showBoard(char board[], int turn, int Xp, int Op)
{
cout << "Please enter a number on the board that is the spot you wish to use" << endl;

cout << "Board:\n";

cout << board[0] << " " << board[1] << " " << board[2] << endl;
cout << board[3] << " " << board[4] << " " << board[5] << endl;
cout << board[6] << " " << board[7] << " " << board[8] << endl;

do
{
for (turn=1; turn<10; turn++)
    if (!(turn % 2) == 0)
    {
        cout << "\nPlayer X's turn." << endl;
        cin >> Xp;
        if(Xp=Op) //HERE IS THE CHECKER
        {
            cout << "Spot is taken! Enter new spot: ";
            cin >> Xp;
            board[Xp-1] = 'X';
        }
        else
        {
        board[Xp-1] = 'X';
        }       //WHERE IT ENDS
cout << "Current Board:\n";

cout << board[0] << " " << board[1] << " " << board[2] << endl;
cout << board[3] << " " << board[4] << " " << board[5] << endl;
cout << board[6] << " " << board[7] << " " << board[8] << endl;

winning(board);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nPlayer O's turn." << endl;
        cin >> Op;
        board[Op-1] = 'O';

cout << "Current Board:\n";

cout << board[0] << " " << board[1] << " " << board[2] << endl;
cout << board[3] << " " << board[4] << " " << board[5] << endl;
cout << board[6] << " " << board[7] << " " << board[8] << endl;

winning(board);
    }

}while(turn<10);

cout << "No one won.\n";

return;
}
```

Comment: initialize everything in the array to `'0'`, then if it's a `'0'` you know it hasn't been taken.

Comment: `if(Xp=Op)` I'm quite certain that isn't doing what you think it is. try `==`

Comment: Also, try to use the same code for both players.

Comment: Most important tip: Enable all warnings, and heed them: `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: Changing it to == did the trick! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Initialize everything to a dummy value

Say

```
#define DUMMY_CHAR '.'
```

And chose a char for both Xp and Op

```
#define XP_CHAR 'X'
#define OP_CHAR 'O'
```

And in your check, do

```
if (board[Xp] != DUMMY_CHAR) // Your checker
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are assigning, not checking equality.

Second of all, `Xp == Op` still doesn't make any sense. Check the x spot with an o spot? A better way would be to check if the square if not an `X` nor an `O`:

```
if(board[Xp - 1] != 'X' || board[Xp - 1] != 'O')
```